# Cookie a function via javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

Hello fellow stackoverflow.
I'm up with a new question, here goes.

I would like to stuff the cookie of the following function in my ajax or javascript but I keep on failing to do ,
Here's my javascript function :

```
<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
}

</script>
```

Now I would like it to appear like something like the below :-

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "https://www.something.com/index.html?affid=" + getQueryVariable("affid");}, 3000);
```

Is it possible to cookied the affid ??

So i would use something like this :

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = "https://www.something.com/index.html?affid=" + getCookie("affid");}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to retrieve the affid from cookie

```
 function getCookie(name) {
     var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
     var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
     return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
 }
```

Remember to set cookie named "affid" with the value on server side. If you want to set cookie from javascript you can make use of the code below.

```
function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
}
```

Comment: So to set it, I have to find createcookie function .. Right?

Comment: You can set cookie from the server side itself. Other wise you can set it from the client side also. Do you want to set it from java script ? Its completely based on your scenario. If you don't mind you can update the question with scenario. (if not satisfied)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

It's a small simple cookie jQuery plugin. `$.addCookie('...` `$.removeCookie(...` etc.